# SimpleXML puts id in closing tag

Tags: php, xml, tags, simplexml

I am crawling myself through various articles, how to make an XML out of a PHP array.

Got it to work, with two articles from here, using SimpleXML and a loop.

I used this:

```
function array_to_xml( $data, $xml_data ) {
foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
    if( is_numeric($key) ){
        $key = 'point id="'.$key.'"'; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
    }
    if( is_array($value) ) {
        $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
        array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
    } else {
        $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
    }
}
```

}

and it does kind of work now.

The point is, I am using multi-dimensional arrays to send over article-lists. You might guess, that

```
<article id="sth">bla</article>
```

is a thing.
The problem is, that this function includes the id in the closing tags, so things look like this:

```
<article id="a-1-0">Example of Naming</article id="a-1-0">
```

which makes opening and reading these (also using SimpleXML) impossible.

Is there a way to configure SimpleXML not to create the id in the closing tags? Thx in advance, any help is of great value.

EDIT:

The Code-Snippet above is dealing with the point tags. Same problem There, they look like

```
<point id="0">[...]</point id="0">
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `addAttribute("$key", htmlspecialchars("$value"))` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$el = $xml_data->addChild('point', htmlspecialchars("$value"));
$el->addAttribute('id', $key);
```

Add the attribute after adding the child.

Hope I was Helpful.

Comment: Part of it. The problem is, I have two of those cases. I have severat points and sereval articles within, that didn't come out in the first place, apologies.

Comment: it's
<points>
   <point with id>
        <articles>
            <article with id/>
        </articles>
    </point>
</points>

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand. This didn't solve your problem?

Comment: @plachty can you put up a pastebin with some sample XML?